# wkhtmltopdf return blank page

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I can't convert my php to pdf with wkhtmltopdf.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

ob_start();
require 'pdf/test.html';
$content = ob_get_clean();
$pdf = new \mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf($content);
$pdf->send();
```

I install composer and wkhtmltopdf on my PC is when I launch my code I have a blank page.

do you have a solution to offer me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you acept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use, change '/path/to/page.html' to your page link/url :

```
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

// You can pass a filename, a HTML string, an URL or an options array to the constructor
$pdf = new Pdf('/path/to/page.html');

// On some systems you may have to set the path to the wkhtmltopdf executable
// $pdf->binary = 'C:\...';

if (!$pdf->saveAs('/path/to/page.pdf')) {
    $error = $pdf->getError();
    // ... handle error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Simone Rossaini.

I added this line and it works, and I replace send () with saveAs () but the css does not load.

```
//path to the wkhtmltopdf executable
$pdf->binary = 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf';
$pdf->saveAs('pdf/report.pdf');
```